# Como substituir/otimizar múltiplos ifs em C?

Tags: c, if

Sou iniciante em linguagem C, estou fazendo uma atividade que é para cadastrar alunos e médias em uma lista duplamente encadeada, está tudo funcionando, porem acredito que estou utilizando demasiados ifs, há alguma forma de fazer essas condições sem utilizar tantos ifs?

Uma parte do código:

```
int editar(aluno *alunoPtr){
aluno *tmp;
int edita, aux=0;
tmp=alunoPtr->prox;
if(vazia(alunoPtr)){
    printf("A LISTA ESTA VAZIA!!!\n");
}else{
    printf("Numero de matricula: ");
    scanf("%i", &edita);
    while(tmp){
        if(edita == tmp->matricula){
            printf("\nMedia final: ");
            scanf("%f", &tmp->mediaFinal);
            if(tmp->mediaFinal >= 0 && tmp->mediaFinal <= 10){
                printf("\nMEDIA CADASTRADA COM SUCESSO!\n");
            }else{
                printf("\nMEDIA INVALIDA!\n");
            };
            aux++;
            break;
        };
        tmp=tmp->prox;
    };
    if(aux==0){
        printf("\nNUMERO DE MATRICULA INVALIDO!\n");
    };
};
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando o return para retornar o `aux` quando a edição for realizada com suceso e -1 quando ocorrer algum erro é possível retirar o último `if` e alguns `else`s.

```
   int editar(aluno *alunoPtr) {
     aluno *tmp;
     int edita, aux = 0;
     tmp = alunoPtr->prox;
     if (vazia(alunoPtr)) {
       printf("A LISTA ESTA VAZIA!!!\n");
       return -1;
     }
     printf("Numero de matricula: ");
     scanf("%i", &edita);
     while (tmp) {
       if (edita == tmp->matricula) {
         printf("\nMedia final: ");
         scanf("%f", &tmp->mediaFinal);
         aux++;
         if (tmp->mediaFinal >= 0 && tmp->mediaFinal <= 10) {
           printf("\nMEDIA CADASTRADA COM SUCESSO!\n");
           return aux;
         } 
         printf("\nMEDIA INVALIDA!\n");
         return -1;
       };
       tmp=tmp->prox;
     };
     printf("\nNUMERO DE MATRICULA INVALIDO!\n");
     return -1;
   };
```